# MySQL connect on many content sites

Tags: mysql

I´m using MySQL connect to get my informations out of a database. I need these informations on many content sites of my webpage, so i don´t want to copy this all the time:

```
<?php $verbindung = mysql_connect ("xxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx") or die ("xxxxx"); mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die ("xxxxxx"); ?>
```

Is there a comfortable and safer solution for this?

Comment: Common code should be put in an include file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dbconnect.php and include that with the files that need to connect.

In the dbconnect.php create a function like so

```
function dbiConnect($db = "[default table]") {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx", "xxx",$db);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error){
        echo "Could not connect to database;

    }
    else {
        return $mysqli;
    }
}
```

You can pass in the table name as a parameter, if it is not the default table you specify in the function.

The call will look like...

```
$connection = dbiconnect("[table_name]");
```

You can also call without passing in the table name, in which case the table you select will be the specified default table in your function call.

Comment: Is this a safe solution or are there any risks if the informatiosn are in an extern file?

Comment: Yes. It will be as safe as any of your other files in the directory.